# Import miniSerializeError from redux-toolkit

Tags: redux-toolkit

I am trying to import the miniSerializeError function from redux toolkit. To me it looks like the function is exported in: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/4ad8be674187c2122b2fd0d499c61ab77cfec072/src/index.ts#L123 but i cant find the function in the build.
Does anyone know it this is a bug or the function just is not exported?

Link to the function: https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/blob/4ad8be674187c2122b2fd0d499c61ab77cfec072/src/createAsyncThunk.ts#L57

Comment: Looks like you figured out the solution and then deleted your answer.  It's perfectly fine to answer your own question!  I have voted to undelete.  Please correct me if I am misunderstanding.

Comment: No, the solution did not work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded to recent most version (1.6.1) of redux-toolkit and it worked.

`miniSerializeError` is exported from version 1.6.0.
So make sure of the version of redux-toolkit in your `package.json`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: Can you let me know what I missed, I think I answered the issue.

Comment: Sorry, the response wasn't phrased correctly. Firstly, thank you for contributing :) This answer doesn't point out what the original mistake was / may have been. Of course, the question did not give much information to refer to (you may even want to avoid such questions). Your answer could be improved by giving more detail on what you think the mistake is. Small tips like this usually better fit a comment and not a full fledged answer. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer for some guidance